# Joomla Query Array Error

Tags: php, sql, arrays, joomla, syntax-error

I'm new to joomla jdatabase. Currently I having a error code on my query in joomla which I using *sourcerer* plugin to insert the code.

Here is my code:

```
$campusID = $_POST['campusID'];

$courseID = $_POST['courseID'];

// Get default database object
$db =JFactory::getDBO();

// Get a new JDatabaseQuery object
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$tmpIds = array();

foreach($courseID as $cId){

$tmpIds = $db->quote($cId); //sanitize the input

}

$courseID1 = explode($tmpIds, ",");

// Build the query
$query->select($db->quoteName('courseid'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('intake'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('campusid').'='. $db->quote($campusID));

 $query->where($db->quoteName('courseid').'IN('.$courseID1.')');

// Set the query for the DB oject to execute
$db->setQuery($query);
// Get the DB object to load the results as a list of objects
$results = $db->loadObjectList(); 

if($results){

 echo 'Good';

}
else{ echo 'Error';}
```

Apparently, the `courseID` is an array that post by other form and it was using a check box. But somehow maybe my logic thinking is bad, I couldn't found anyway to compare the `courseID` with the database `courseID` to determine whether the `courseID` is existing in the database or not, else it might just prompt the error message.

Here is what error message I get from joomla when I am trying to execute it.

```
Error 1054. Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause' SQL=SELECT `courseid` FROM `intake` WHERE `campusid`='Campus2' AND `courseid`IN(Array)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

first of all you have a change of

```
$tmpIds = $db->quote($cId);
```

To

```
$tmpIds[] = $db->quote($cId);
```

after you want to use a `implode()`

```
$courseID1 = explode($tmpIds, ",");
```

To

```
$courseID1 = implode(',',$tmpIds);
```